# Shared library linker error on access to global variable of executable

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

My C++ application uses `dlopen` and friends to implement a plugin system, where shared libraries are loaded as necessary.

Part of the application is a preprocessor macro

```
#define LOG_STREAM (lock_guard<mutex>(CERR_MUTEX), cerr)
```

that I use to protect `cerr <<` expressions. `CERR_MUTEX` is a global `std::mutex` variable that is defined in a .cpp with a corresponding `extern` declaration in the header. `LOG_STREAM` is used throughout the executable without problems.

The plugins use `LOG_STREAM` for their logging messages as well. Unfortunately though, plugin compilation fails with a linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CERR_MUTEX"
```

I use cmake for the plugin compilation. The related lines in the CMakeLists are

```
file(GLOB WORKLOAD_SOURCES "workloads/*.cpp")
foreach(SRC ${WORKLOAD_SOURCES})
    get_filename_component(WORKLOAD_NAME ${SRC} NAME_WE)

    add_library(${WORKLOAD_NAME} MODULE ${SRC})
    set_target_properties(${WORKLOAD_NAME} PROPERTIES ${TARGETPROPS})
    target_link_libraries(${WORKLOAD_NAME} ${TBB_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endforeach(SRC)
```

I also tried to replace the plain global variable with a static member of a class. Same error.

Any ideas whats the reason for this and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the linker can not find the variable because the plugin is not *linked against the executable* and can not see the definitions made there.

By chance, the compilation worked for the rest of the plugin because the other symbols were all linked as [*weak symbol*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol), which do not require a definition during linking.

I will refactor the application and move types that are required by plugins into a dedicated shared library. That library can be linked by the executable and plugins alike.